Render webview Android 6
I'm developing a mobile app which shows a webview to users. In android 7.1.1 and higher versions all urls render perfectly fine, but in android 6 I've got some problems with some urls. For example, if I render https://www.amazon.com, it works fine in my android 6 emulator:

But if I try with some other urls, for example https://slack.com/intl/es-ar/, I've got a blank screen:

My kotlin code is the following:
package com.example.webview

import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   private lateinit var webView: WebView

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     enableEdgeToEdge()
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
          val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
          v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
          insets
     }

      webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

      webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

      webView.loadUrl("https://slack.com/intl/es-ar/")

      webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

      webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true

      webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
  }
}

I'm not sure what could be the problem.

Slack is using Let's Encrypt for SSL certificates (at least for that site), and Let's Encrypt only supports Android 7.0 and higher.

Thank you very much for your quick response! This behavior also applies on real android 6 devices, doesn't it? Can Android 6 users update Android System Webview in order to view sites like slack? or is it impossible? I'm trying to find out if this issue can be solved for those users.

@LucasAcuña: "This behavior also applies on real android 6 devices, doesn't it?" -- correct. "Can Android 6 users update Android System Webview in order to view sites like slack?" -- I do not think that is possible. Please bear in mind that Android 6 was released in 2015, 9 years ago.

Yes, I'm aware of that. I was just wondering if there was any posible solution that didn't involve developing a native view for Android 6 or using a site that doesn't use Let's Encrypt for SSL certificates. Thanks for your help!

@LucasAcuña: "I was just wondering if there was any posible solution that didn't involve developing a native view for Android 6 or using a site that doesn't use Let's Encrypt for SSL certificates" -- you could see if GeckoView uses platform SSL support or something from Mozilla. If it is the latter, that might work with Let's Encrypt even on older devices.
